# What does "lost promise" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

English is not my native language, can somebody explain what does "lost promise" mean?

Here the article - [Someday (Nickelback song)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Someday_(Nickelback_song))

> The lyrics chronicle a *lost promise*; the singer talks about how a relationship failed and he wonders "how the hell'd we wind up like this". He wishes that they could discuss their issues and that the relationship will come back someday but that someday never comes because it's a lost promise.

Comment: Please consider whether the 'meaning-in-context' tag is more appropriate for your question. Either way, you need to give us more information about how the words are being used before we can give answers which will help not only you, but others in the future. You should also explain what research you have done and why it hasn't helped you. eg if you looked up 'lost' and 'promise' in the dictionary, were there meanings which could make a plausible combined one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Lost** *adjective*
> 2 That has been taken away or cannot be recovered.
> ‘if only one could recapture one's lost youth’
> 2.1  (of time or an opportunity) not used advantageously; wasted.
> ‘the decision meant a lost opportunity to create 200 jobs’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lost)
>
> **Promise** *noun*
> 1 A declaration or assurance that one will do something or that a particular thing will happen.
> ‘what happened to all those firm promises of support?’
> **Promise** *verb*
> 1.1 (archaic, with object) Pledge (someone, especially a woman) to marry someone else; betroth.
> ‘I've been promised to him for years’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/promise)

The [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/nickelback/someday.html) relate to a failed relationship. Guessing the author's intentions would venture into literary criticism, which is off-topic on this site. So a representative range of interpretations will have to suffice.

Relationships often carry promises (implied or express) such as fidelity and support. When people don't live up to those promises, the promises may be said to be *broken*.

*Lost promises* isn't a typical English phrase. In the given context, though, if one party *breaks* a promise, it could be argued that the other party *loses* that promise. The *loss* might be considered either something merely unrecoverable or something wasted, and *promise* can be understood either as a declaration made by the parties, or as the parties themselves. Understanding the phrase *lost promise* involves selecting an appropriate interpretation for each word.